# Изменение данных в sim чипе

Tags: файлы

Имеется картридж для термоструйного принтера (проставляется дата при производстве).
В связи с тем, что у поставщика сбои в поставках картриджей, вопрос:
возможно ли перезаписать информацию об остатках чернил на чипе? т.к. есть возможность покупать картриджи без чипов, но они не принимаются принтером, если ставить любой родной чип- все читается, но при расходе более 105%, чип не дает запустить картридж.
[image: Картридж]

[image: Картридж1]

[image: Чип]